# How to Upload Pdf,Docx,txt files in FireBase using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, file, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Swift Programming and FireBase, I have Implemented Chat Application Which I can upload only Images and Videos its working fine.Now I want to Upload files like Docx,txt,pdf also,I Have Surfed lot,But I never found any solution for this ,is their possible to upload the files also,can anyone suggest me a solution for that.

here the some of the code to upload and download images and videos

```
//Code to send Images and Videos 
       // MARK: - Send media message
    func sendMedia(message : MSMessage, senderRef : FIRDatabaseReference,image : Data?, video : URL? ){
        let image_videos: String?
        if image != nil{
            image_videos = "Send you a Photo"
            let uniqeID : String = "\(NSUUID().uuidString).jpg"

            // save photo in firebase storage
            DBManager.manager.imageStorageRef.child(Constants.USERS_IMAGES_STORAGE)
                .child(message.senderId).child(uniqeID)
                .put(image!, metadata: nil){
                    (metadata : FIRStorageMetadata?, err : Error?) in
                    // problem with upload image
                    if err != nil{ // Error occurred, infrom the user
                        self.delegate?.errorOccurred(description: (err?.localizedDescription)!)
                    }else{// send link to photo in user messages
                        let url = String(describing: metadata!.downloadURL()!)
                        self.sendMessage(message: message, senderRef: senderRef, url : url, fileName : uniqeID)

                    }
            }// dbmanager
        }else{
            let uniqeID : String = NSUUID().uuidString
            image_videos = "Send you a Video"
            // save video in firebase storage
            DBManager.manager.videoStorageRef.child(Constants.USERS_VIDEOS_STORAGE)
                .child(message.senderId).child(uniqeID).putFile(video!, metadata : nil ){
                    (metadata : FIRStorageMetadata?, err : Error?) in
                    // problem with upload video
                    if err != nil{ // Error occurred, infrom the user
                        self.delegate?.errorOccurred(description: (err?.localizedDescription)!)
                    }else{// send link to video in user messages
                        let url = String(describing: metadata!.downloadURL()!)
                        self.sendMessage(message: message, senderRef: senderRef, url : url, fileName : uniqeID)


                    }
            }
        }  }


//Code to receive Images and videos
// MARK : - Observe Handler
    func observeHandler(snapshot : FIRDataSnapshot) {

        guard let data = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary else{
            return
        }

        // check if there is data
        guard let senderID = data[Constants.SENDER_ID] as? String,
            let senderName = data[Constants.SENDER_NAME] as? String,
            let sentDate = data[Constants.SENT_DATE] as? Int,
            let text = data[Constants.SENDER_TEXT] as? String,
            let receiverID = data[Constants.RECEIVER_ID] as? String,
            let fileURL = data[Constants.MEDIA_URL] as? String ,
            let fileName = data[Constants.FILE_NAME] as? String,
            let messageID = data[Constants.MESSAGE_ID] as? String else{
                debugPrint("\(#function ) error return")
                return
        }

        if !text.isEmpty{ //Text message
            let ReceiveID =  UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "ReceiveID")
            if AuthManager.User.id.value == receiverID && ReceiveID == senderID {
            // create new message object
            let newMessage = MSMessage(senderId: senderID,
                                       senderDisplayName: senderName,
                                       date: self.millisToDate(sentDate), text: text,
                                       receiverID : receiverID,
                                       messageID: messageID)

            // notify caller
            self.delegate?.messageReceived(message : newMessage, fromNode: false)
            }

        }else if !fileURL.isEmpty{ // Media message

            guard let mediaURL = URL(string: fileURL) else{
                return
            }

            // If the media is Image
            if self.isImage(fileURL){
                self.getImage(mediaURL,senderID,senderName,receiverID,sentDate,messageID, fileName: fileName)
            }else{ // Media is video
                self.getVideo(mediaURL,senderID,senderName,receiverID,sentDate,messageID, fileName: fileName)
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Get video
    func getVideo(_ mediaURL : URL,_  senderID : String,_  senderName : String,_ receiverID : String,
                  _  sentDate : Int, _ messageID : String , fileName : String,completion: ((MSMessage)->())? = nil){

        DispatchQueue.global().sync {

            let video = JSQVideoMediaItem(maskAsOutgoing: senderID == AuthManager.User.id.value ? true : false)
            video?.fileURL = mediaURL
            video?.isReadyToPlay = true
            let newMessage = MSMessage(senderId: senderID,
                                       displayName: senderName,
                                       media: video!,
                                       date: (self.millisToDate(sentDate)),
                                       receiverID: receiverID,
                                       messageID: messageID,
                                       mediaURL : mediaURL,
                                       fileName : fileName)


            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if completion != nil{
                    completion!(newMessage)
                }else{
                    self.delegate?.mediaReceived(message: newMessage)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show the code of images and videos and then we can suggest the changes required for docs,txt, pdf

Comment: I have updated  my code

Comment: after I fetched file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F6D15E35-2DC5-4A57-9E2C-7CEF1F6DEDDB/tmp/com.prematix.test-Inbox/AHMPM1433E-2018.pdf from iPhone I don't know how to store on firebase storage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the code

```
// Get a reference to the storage service using the default Firebase App
let storage = Storage.storage()

// Create a storage reference from our storage service
let storageRef = storage.reference()

// File located on disk
let localFile = URL(string: "path/to/docs/rivers.pdf")!

    // Create a reference to the file you want to upload
    let riversRef = storageRef.child("docs/rivers.pdf")

    // Upload the file to the path "docs/rivers.pdf"
    let uploadTask = riversRef.putFile(from: localFile, metadata: nil) { metadata, error in
      guard let metadata = metadata else {
        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
        return
      }
      // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type.
      let size = metadata.size
      // You can also access to download URL after upload.
      storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
        guard let downloadURL = url else {
          // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
          return
        }
      }
    }
```

> For more info please refer to the firebase iOS doc here:
>   https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files

Comment: I have tried this code but nothing is stored in firebase storage.

Comment: Are you sure you have the read write access ? Any error in the console ?

Comment: Hello Moaz Khan thanks a lot ..I can able to upload my Pdf files in fireBase storage..thanks for ur contribution

Comment: Thanks a lot working as expected. Great Work. Keep Going